# How to create dictionary<int, list<float>>

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a key value pair where the key is an int and the value is a list. I want this hard coded but I haven't used unity in a while and cant tell what I am doing wrong. I know its probably something simple but I cant find example of dictionaries with lists.

```
Dictionary<int, List<float> data = new Dictionary<int, List<float>() {
        {0, [1.0f, 0.5f]},
        {1, [1.0f, 0.5f]}
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `[ ]` to define a new `List`. You need to use the same kind of notation as when you defined the new `Dictionary`. That is, `new Type() { }`.

In your case, it looks like this:

```
var data = new Dictionary<int, List<float>>() {
        {0, new List<float>() { 1.0f, 0.5f } },
        {1, new List<float>() { 1.0f, 0.5f } }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

First, it's `Dictionary<int, List<float>>` not `Dictionary<int, List<float>` (you're missing an ending angle bracket)

Second, you can initialize dictionaries like `[0] = new List<float> { 1.0f, 0.5f }`

Example:

```
var data = new Dictionary<int, List<float>>
{
  [0] = new List<float> { 1.0f, 0.5f },
  [1] = new List<float> { 1.0f, 0.5f }
}
```